# Error 1072 MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep on getting error 1072 when trying to add a foreign key attribute and linking my attribute to another table. I've tried different ways of writing this but I keep on getting the message that "department_id doesn't exist in the table". If you could give me a hand that would be awesome! thank you so so much!

Here is the my code:

```
Alter table employee
add constraint department_fk
foreign key ( department_id)
references department(department_id);
```

And here is the rest of my tables:

```
Create table Department (
    department_id integer auto_increment primary key not null,
    department_name varchar (50) not null,
    Office_number varchar(50) not null,
    phone char (20) not null
);


Create table employee (
    employee_id integer auto_increment primary key not null,
    first_name varchar (25) not null,
    last_name varchar (25) not null,
    phone char(20) not null,
    email varchar (100) not null,
    salary decimal (10,2)
);

Create table project (
    project_id integer auto_increment primary key not null,
    max_hours time not null,
    start_date datetime not null,
    end_date datetime not null,
    Project_lead integer,
    Constraint project_fk1 
    foreign key (employee_id)
    references employee(employee_id),
    Department_id integer,
    Constraint project_fk2 
    foreign key (department_id) 
    references department (department_id)  
);

Create table assignment (
    employee_id integer not null,
    project_id integer not null,
    hours_worked time not null,
    primary key (employee_id, project_id),
    constraint assignment_fk1 
    foreign key(employee_id) 
    references employee(employee_id),
    constraint assignment_fk2 
    foreign key (project_id) 
    references project(project_id)
);

Alter table project
drop foreign key department_id;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Foreign key column in your employee table:

```
Create table employee (
   employee_id integer auto_increment primary key not null,
   first_name varchar (25) not null,
   last_name varchar (25) not null,
   phone char(20) not null,
   email varchar (100) not null,

   dept_id integer,

   salary decimal (10,2)
);

Alter table employee
add constraint department_fk
foreign key ( dept_id)
references department(department_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Trust the message ;) - the column "department_id" doesn't exist in your employee table!